# Hover using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I would like to do. I have 2 identical lists that I would like to have change color on hover of a specific item on both lists simultaneously.

Example:

**List One**
List Item 1
List Item 2
 
List Item 3

**List Two**
List Item 1
List Item 2
 
List Item 3

So if you were to hover over List One's first item it would highlight List Two's first item also.

Any help on this would save my life thanks very much. V

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
<style>
.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
<body>
<ul id="list1">
 <li>foo</li>
 <li>bar</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2">
 <li>foo</li>
 <li>bar</li>
</ul>
<script>
(function() {
    var list1 = document.getElementById('list1'),
        list2 = document.getElementById('list2');

    function setActive(target, b) {
        if(!target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') return;

        // determine position in list:
        for(var i = 0; target = target.previousSibling; ++i);

        list1.childNodes[i].className = b ? 'active' : '';
        list2.childNodes[i].className = b ? 'active' : '';
    }

    // mouseover/mouseout are bubbling, so add the listeners to parents:

    list1.onmouseover = list2.onmouseover = function(event) {
        setActive((event && event.target) || window.event.srcElement, true);
    };

    list1.onmouseout = list2.onmouseout = function(event) {
        setActive((event && event.target) || window.event.srcElement, false);
    };
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, you could use jquery to select a specific  tag in each list and apply a style to it. Maybe use the .addClass method to add a css style to the same items in the array of  tags for both select lists.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <ul id="list1">
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
 </ul>

 <ul id="list2">
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
 </ul>
```

jQuery

```
 $("#list1 li").hover(
         function(){
                var ind = $("#list1 li").index($(this));
               $("#list2 li:eq(" + ind + ")").addClass("highlight"); 
               $(this).addClass("highlight");
         },
         function(){
         var ind = $("#list1 li").index($(this));
              $("#list2 li:eq(" + ind + ")").removeClass("highlight");
                               $(this).removeClass("highlight");
         }
   );
```

The highlight class will have the style that you wish to apply to both lists.